# Smooth Scrolling on Touch Event

Tags: android, scroll

I currently have a view which needs to scroll on touch (can't use scrollview or scrollby). At the moment you can see that I am simply adding .5f which is not very smooth or useful. I want the same effect as the drop down navigation bar in the newer android (also need to know the current Y offset every frame so that it can be used to calculate other effects as well).

Any ideas or help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
    drawerCardWallet.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
            if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();                                 
            }
            else {
                mVelocityTracker.clear();
            }
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {                              

            moveY = event.getRawY();
            if(drawerCardWallet.getY() > topHeaderLayout.getBottom() || cardImage.getY() < (topFooterMainLayout.getHeight()*2) - (cardImage.getHeight()/100*25)) {
                cardCurrentOffset = cardImage.getY();
                drawerWalletCurrentOffset = drawerCardWallet.getY();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                velocityX = VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId);
                velocityY = VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId);

                if(Math.abs(velocityX) + 100 > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
                    // right left
                }
                else {
                    // up down                          
                    if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {                           
                        if(moveY > previousRawY) {
                            // Moving down

                            if(drawerCardWallet.getY() < screenHeight - (topFooterMainLayout.getHeight()*2) - (cardImage.getHeight()/100*25)) {                                 
                                for(float i=0;i<moveY-previousRawY;i++) {
                                    cardCurrentOffset += .5f;
                                    drawerWalletCurrentOffset += .5f;

                                    cardImage.setTranslationY(cardCurrentOffset);
                                    drawerCardWallet.setTranslationY(drawerWalletCurrentOffset);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            // Moving Up

                            if(drawerCardWallet.getY() >= topHeaderLayout.getHeight()+3) {

                                for(float i=0;i<previousRawY-moveY;i++) {
                                    cardCurrentOffset -= .5f;
                                    drawerWalletCurrentOffset -= .5f;

                                    cardImage.setTranslationY(cardCurrentOffset);
                                    drawerCardWallet.setTranslationY(drawerWalletCurrentOffset);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        previousRawY = moveY;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);                                 
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `scrollview`?

Comment: you got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342995/android-smooth-vertical-scroll-on-touch